# Input textbox in html form working fine on Firefox not working on Chrome and Safari

Tags: google-chrome, safari, mozilla, forms, textinput

I have a submit form in my website which works well with Firefox but does not work on Chrome and Safari. The input textbox is the only element giving trouble, all the other elements work fine with every browser. Do someone have a solution for this?

Here is the code of the textbox:

```
<div class="form-input-half-left form-input-border">
    <div class="form-input-background opacity_2"></div>
    <input id="name" type="text" name="x_first_name" value="name *" onclick="this.value = '';"/>
    <span class="error"> <?php echo $x_first_nameErr;?></span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried your code [here in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LtnB9/) and works fine in both chrome and firefox.i couldn't replicate the error, but i think you can use `placeholder` for your purpose and it works much more better than `onclick`

```
<input id="name" type="text" name="x_first_name" placeholder="name *"/>
```

may i know the problem is on which version of chrome and what is the problem exactly? it doesn't clear the text box or something else?

Comment: I tried it but, not able to enter text. It is not responding. All the other elements in the form works. The whole form works well in jsfiddle.

Chrome Version 34.0.1847.116 Ubuntu 14.04 aura